# How do I draw my networkx graphs in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, networkx

I have a couple of functions to draw different graphs in networkx to draw train lines on the London underground. It works fine but I want to move it to a tkinter window. I have a working set of windows with a different frame for each train line. I just don't know how to integrate the two so the function draws into the window!
Here is the function I would use to draw the graph:

```
def drawPiccadilly(pos):
    #a dictionary declaring the labels for each node
    labels = {"Uxbridge(P)":"Uxbridge", "Rayners Lane(P)":"Rayners Lane", "Ealing Common(P)":"Ealing Common", "South Ealing(P)":"South Ealing", "Heathrow(P)":"Heathrow", "Hammersmith(P)":"Hammersmith", "Earls Court(P)":"Earls Court",
           "South Kensington(P)":"South Kensington", "Green Park(P)":"Green Park", "Piccadilly Circus(P)":"Piccadilly Circus", "Leicester Square(P)":"Leicester Square", "Holborn(P)":"Holborn", "Kings Cross St Pancras(P)":"Kings Cross St Pancras", "Finsbury Park(P)":"Finsbury Park", "Cockfosters(P)":"Cockfosters"}
    #a dictionary declaring the label positions
    PLabelPos = {"Uxbridge(P)":(-1300,1000), "Rayners Lane(P)":(-1100,1000), "Ealing Common(P)":(-1100,-100), "South Ealing(P)":(-1200,-400), "Heathrow(P)":(-1200,-750), "Hammersmith(P)":(-900,-250), "Earls Court(P)":(-700,-300),
           "South Kensington(P)":(-400,-600), "Green Park(P)":(-100,-300), "Piccadilly Circus(P)":(0,100), "Leicester Square(P)":(300,-200), "Holborn(P)":(500,500), "Kings Cross St Pancras(P)":(500,1000), "Finsbury Park(P)":(60,1200), "Cockfosters(P)":(600,1350)}
    #drawing the Piccadilly graph
    networkx.draw(Piccadilly, pos, node_color="purple", edge_color="blue", node_size = 100)
    networkx.draw_networkx_labels(Piccadilly, PLabelPos, labels, font_size=6)
```

My window is pretty generic, just a container and some buttons switching between frames.
This is what I tried to do but it just doesn't work. It either comes up with an attribute error or 'figure doesn't exist in module'

```
def drawPiccadilly():
    f = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot()
    a.draw(Piccadilly, node_color="purple", edge_color="blue", node_size = 100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: it seems you use `matplotlib` and there are tutorial (and questions on `Stackoverflow`) how to embed `matplotlib` in `tkinter`. Using only `draw()` you can't put image in `tkinter` window

Comment: matplotlib documentation: [Embedding in Tk](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)